# Remove HTML remove aligment using Java

Tags: html, java, htmleditorkit

I Have faces a issue with removeing alignment In HTML document.

```
 <html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p style="margin-top: 0" align="center">
      Hello World
    </p>
    <p style="margin-top: 0" align="center">
      Java World
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

My Issue is how to remove alignment of first paragraph with out affecting second paragraph . If I use regex it will it will remove alignment of second para also. I really appricite you any comment regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [replaceFirst](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) function.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to show you another way for that. It would be quite simple to use CSS pseudo-class: `:first-child`. According to your code above:

```
body p:first-child { text-align: left !important; }
```

Second thing would be to use JavaScript or any JS library, like jQuery to remove this property from first `p` element, e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").first().css("text-align","left");
});
```

Comment: AFAIK pseudo classes are not well implemented(supported) in all browsers(http://www.webdevout.net/browser-support-css#css2pseudoclasses)